# Flutter Plugin: No code intellisense in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am having a problem with Flutter and Android Studio: I want to create a Flutter plugin, but Flutter's dependencies don't seem to be downloaded or indexed in Android Studio. I do not have code intellisense: the classes FlutterPLugin & MethodCallHandler have the "Cannot find declaration to go to", I cannot see the method that I have to override to satisfy the interface implementation... (see the screenshoot below)
[image]

Here is the process I am doing:

1. I create a new Flutter project with the plugin template using the following command `flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin --platforms=android,ios -a kotlin plugin_camerakit`.
2. Open the `plugin_camerakit` project in Android Studio. (or IntelliJ IDEA)
3. Download the flutter plugin from Android Studio
4. Restart Android Studio
5. Open the dart plugin setting to set the dart SDK path, and open the flutter setting and set the flutter SDK path.
6. Open the file `./android/main/com/example/plugin_camerakit/CamerakitPlugin.kt'.
7. Click "Open for editing in Android Studio".
   [image]
8. Wait for the Android Studio panel to appear, and wait for the end of the gradle build.
9. And here is my problem, I have no code intellisense: the classes `FlutterPLugin` & `MethodCallHandler` have the "Cannot find declaration to go to".
   [image].

I tried to reinstall IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio & Flutter, no results.
I also downloaded JAVA jdk-20 and specified the `JAVA_HOME`, same problem.

Here is my `flutter doctor` problem:

```
Doctor summary (to see all the details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1555], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 17.4.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2023.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.77.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of install/uninstall process, I found out my problem. I noticed that flutter/Android Studio have different Java JDK location, which made some conflicts...
So I uninstalled Android Studio/flutter, deleted my `~/.gradle`, `~/.jdk` folders and my android SDK folder. I reinstalled Android Studio/flutter, set the environment variables, downloaded the SDK tools. Set the `JAVA_HOME` with the embedded Java JDK (located in the `jbr` of the Android Studio directory).

I recreated a project and this worked!

Hope this can be useful.